# Multiple images upload using paperclip gem and update image

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, image-uploading

I'm trying to upload multiple images to my system. I'm using `paperclip gem` to deal with it, but I'm having 2 problems.

1 - how to save multiple images in a hash?
2 - how do I update/insert the image?

The user has to select all the products that he wants to update (`check_box_tag`) and select all the images that he wants to upload. If the product has the same name as the image, it saves the alteration.

This is my `altprod` function in product_controller. It deals with the actions, but the only part that matters is the import:

```
def altprod
    case params[:commit]
    (...)
    when "Import"
      slctProd = params[:selected_products]
      slctProd.each do |prod|
        if prod.eql? File.basename(params[:image].original_filename, ".*")
          #Here is the problem :'(
          Product.where(code: prod).update(image: :image)
        end
      end
      redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Insert/update images succeeded.'
    end
  end
```

And here is the code to upload the files:

```
<%= form_tag altprod_products_path, multipart: true  do %>
    (...)
    <%= file_field_tag :image, multiple: true %>
    <%= submit_tag "Import", method: :post %>
    <br/>
    (...)
<% end %>
```

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
Here `avatar` is image field name.I think you ran paperclip command right to generate image model.

```
#Product Controller

if params[:images]
  params[:images].each { |image|
    @product.create_image(avatar: image, user_id: current_user.id)
  }
end
```

## Form

```
<%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file,:required => true %>
```

## Image Model

```
belongs_to :product
has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png",
                     size: { in: 0..1000.kilobytes },
                      url: "/system/:hash.:extension",
              hash_secret: "abc123"
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
validates_attachment :avatar, :presence => true,

      :size => { :in => 0..5000.kilobytes}
```

## Product Model

```
has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
```

This type of hash is created by paperclip

```
[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f90b22c5340 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170929-7646-eqf009.jpeg>, @original_filename="job_post.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"book_image[]\"; filename=\"job_post.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f90b22c52f0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170929-7646-1qhrsy8.jpeg>, @original_filename="query.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"book_image[]\"; filename=\"query.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :))